# Is it possible to mine alumni information from FaceBook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Basically, I'd like to extract a list of people that have graduated from a specific university, something like [this query provides](http://www.facebook.com/search.php#!/search.php?q=&type=users&init=srp&ed=16777479&ny=&lo=).

I can have an authorized user from the educational organization that mines the alumnis to log in - but it seems to me that even if I get the list, I won't be able to extract much information about these people - to be useful, the app needs to extract things like which city the person lives in, current occupation etc.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No obviously you can't. You need at least each user that is not friend of you to authorize your application with a certain [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) to be able to get the data you are seeking.